# While inserting a new lead update trigger is executed

Tags: apex, before-trigger, after-trigger

Created a new trigger with below code :

```
trigger LeadSourceUpdate on Lead (before insert,before update,after update) {

    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){
        if(Trigger.isBefore){
            if(Trigger.isUpdate){
           l.Email = 'Update@test.com'; 
             }  
            if(String.IsBlank(l.Email)  && Trigger.isInsert){
             l.Email = 'Insert@test.com'; 
            }              
        }
    } 
}
```

Now after the trigger was saved and when I created a new lead record, I expected the email field with value as Insert@test.com but on creation of the lead the email field had the value as Update@test.com. Can anyone explain on why this happened?

Comment: There might be some other flow/process builder etc. which updated the lead after creation causing the update block to be executed. You can try adding field history tracking for Email and check it.

Comment: It seems like there are some process occuring right after lead creation, even though there are no flows/processbuilders/duplicaterules are running.

Comment: What do the debug logs say?

Comment: there are no flows which update the email field, and the logs also say that is updated by a trigger

Comment: Lead assignment rules will cause an Update action (plus any legacy WFR or Process Builder). There could also be managed packages with their own automation